# I don't understand why I'm getting this error "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python

I'm super new to programming, like it's been less than a week and I've been tasked to write this simple program that uses functions that I wrote.
From what I know, I don't understand why the code isn't working.
this is my code:

```
def filter_teens(a=13, b=13, c=13):

    def fix_age(age):
        if (int(age) < 15 and int(age) >= 13) or (int(age) > 16 and int(age) <= 19) :
            new_num = int(age) - int(age)
            return new_num


    if a != 15 or a != 16:
        result_a =  fix_age(a)
    else:
        result_a = int(a)

    if b != 15 or b != 16:
        result_b = fix_age(b)
    else:
        result_b = int(b)

    if c != 15 or c != 16:
        result_c = fix_age(c)
    else:
        result_c = int(c)

    final_result = int(result_a) + int(result_b) + (result_c)
    return final_result


sum = int(filter_teens(15, 13, 16)) ### I receive the error here
print(sum)
```

Comment: Please post the full error traceback when asking about errors in your code

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](/q/25385173/843953)
Learning [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is an extremely valuable skill for a programmer.
Please go through the linked page and apply the techniques described there to your problem to narrow down the cause of the error. 
Then ask a specific question. _"Why is my code doing this"_ is [too broad for Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/843953)

Comment: Please also take the [tour], read [ask] and [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Try to think what happens in `fix_age` if the `age` doesn't pass the criteria

Comment: `if a != 15 or a != 16:` will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

Your "a" value of 15 doesn't satisfy the conditional in your fix_age function that returns a value.  By the logic, a value is only returned if the value passed to fix_age is 13, 14, 17, 18, or 19.  Since "a" is 15 the compiler is returning NoneType instead, which can't be converted to an integer.  You'll need to have a return value outside the conditional to accommodate this, or update the conditional.

Answer (score 0):

The return statement in your `fix_age` function is only called inside the if statement. As far as Python is concerned you can always call this function in such a way that the if statement is not satisfied. In that case the function will not return a number but a 'NoneType'. Since every input argument in `filter_teens` is used as input for `fix_age`, they might all potentially be 'NoneType'. Calling `int()` on such a 'NoneType' is not possible, hence the error.

I do not know what your intended goal is, but a fix might be to return the number 0 from the `fix_age` function if the if statement is not True. This would look like this:

```
def fix_age(age):
        if (int(age) < 15 and int(age) >= 13) or (int(age) > 16 and int(age) <= 19) :
            new_num = int(age) - int(age)
            return new_num
        else:
            return 0
```

One extra tip: Python is very good in inferring types, so you can probably lose all the `int()` calls around the numbers in your code and it would still work (and be more easy to read).